# Yang-Mills Field Strength Compatibility Function

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

I've been going through Nakahara's Topology, Geometry and Physics from 2003 and I'm struggling to fully understand this derivation from page 410:

Say there exists two different fields, $\mathcal{F}_i = d\mathcal{A}_i + \mathcal{A}_i\land \mathcal{A}_i$ and $\mathcal{F}_j = d\mathcal{A}_j + \mathcal{A}_j\land \mathcal{A}_j$, then the compatibility function between the two is computed as

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}_j = d(t^{-1}_{ij}\mathcal{A}_it_{ij} +t^{-1}_{ij}dt_{ij}) + (t^{-1}_{ij}\mathcal{A}_it_{ij} +t^{-1}_{ij}dt_{ij})\land (t^{-1}_{ij}\mathcal{A}_it_{ij} +t^{-1}_{ij}dt_{ij})\\
= (-t^{-1}_{ij}dt_{ij}\land t^{-1}_{ij}\mathcal{A}_it_{ij} + t^{-1}_{ij}d\mathcal{A}_it_{ij} -t^{-1}_{ij}\mathcal{A}_i\land dt_{ij} -t^{-1}_{ij}dt_{ij}t^{-1}_{ij}\land dt_{ij})+(t^{-1}_{ij}\mathcal{A}_i\land \mathcal{A}_it_{ij} +t^{-1}_{ij}\mathcal{A}_i\land dt_{ij} + t^{-1}_{ij}dt_{ij}t^{-1}_{ij}\land \mathcal{A}_it_{ij} + t^{-1}_{ij}dt_{ij}\land t^{-1}_{ij}dt_{ij})\\
= t^{-1}_{ij}(d\mathcal{A}_i + \mathcal{A}_i\land \mathcal{A}_i)t_{ij} = t^{-1}_{ij}\mathcal{F}_it_{ij}
\end{equation}

where the compatibility function for gauge potentials has been substituted in and $t_{ij}$ is the transition function. My problems mostly lie with the first term as I'm not entirely sure what the exterior derivative $d$ does in this context. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The exterior derivative here works the same as it would on regular forms, except here the forms are valued in the endomorphism bundle. I think what might be a bit confusing is how they simplified $dt_{ij}^{-1}$. Try to to think about how you can simplify that. **Hint**: $t_{ij}^{-1}t_{ij}=1$.